# Not able to show "Underline, Subscript, Superscript" in Standard Edition CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, toolbar, ckeditor5, ckeditor4.x

The CKEditor Standard Edition may not display all available buttons in the toolbar by default, so you may need to customize the toolbar in the `config.toolbarGroups` option in your JavaScript file.

*Few Buttons not appearing like underline, superscript and subscript*

```
var config={
          extraPlugins:['codesnippet','justify','codeTag','font','floating-tools','base64image','showblocks'],
          codeSnippet_theme:'monokai_sublime',
          skin : 'moono-dark',
          height:356
         }


config.toolbarGroups = [
          { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'undo','clipboard' ] },
          { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
          { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker', 'editing' ] },
          { name: 'forms', groups: [ 'forms' ] },
          { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi', 'paragraph' ] },
          { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
          { name: 'links', groups: [ 'links' ] },
          { name: 'insert', groups: [ 'insert' ] },
          { name: 'styles', groups: [ 'styles' ] },
          { name: 'colors', groups: [ 'colors' ] },
          { name: 'tools', groups: [ 'tools' ] },
          { name: 'others', groups: [ 'others' ] },
          { name: 'about', groups: [ 'about' ] },
           '/'
        ];

config.removeButtons = 'Save,NewPage,Print,Templates,Paste,PasteText,PasteFromWord,SelectAll,Form,Checkbox,Radio,TextField,Textarea,Select,Button,ImageButton,HiddenField,CreateDiv,Language,Anchor,Image,Flash,Iframe,About';

editor = CKEDITOR.replace('editor',config);
```

You can use this option to specify which groups of buttons should be displayed in the toolbar. For example, you might include the basicstyles group to display buttons for bold, italic, and underline formatting, or the paragraph group to display buttons for creating headings, lists, and block quotes.

You can also rearrange the buttons within each group using the [ToolbarConfigurator](https://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/toolbarconfigurator/index.html) feature. This allows you to customize the toolbar layout to suit your specific needs and preferences.

CKEditor Standard Edition toolbar solution